# $L^\infty$ bounds for pseudo-differential equations of parabolic type

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, parabolic-pde, pseudo-differential-operators

It is well-known that if the solution of $u_t=u_{xx}$, with $t>0$ and $x\in\mathbb R$, is bounded, then $a(t)=\sup_{x\in \mathbb R}u(x,t)$ is non-increasing, while
$b(t)=\inf_{x\in \mathbb R}u(x,t)$ is non-decreasing - This is due to the fact that the heat kernel is positive and of unit integral.

Consider now the equation $$u_t=-\lvert \partial_x\rvert^\gamma u, \tag{1}$$ where $\gamma\in\mathbb R_+$, and 
$$
\lvert \partial_x\rvert^\gamma u = \big(\lvert\xi\rvert^\gamma\hat u\big)^{\vee}
\quad\text{or}\quad \lvert \partial_x\rvert^\gamma\bigg(\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\hat u_k\,\mathrm{e}^{ikx}\bigg)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\lvert k\rvert^\gamma \hat u_k\,\mathrm{e}^{ikx}.
$$

Is there any similar $L^\infty$ estimate for the solutions of $(1)$? We assume that $u(x,0)$ is bounded.

Comment: The explicit formula of the fractional heat kernel is not known, but there are upper and lower bounds: https://www.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Fractional_heat_equation In particular, it is positive. That the fractional heat kernel also has unit integral follows form the Fourier expression.

Comment: @WillieWong Your comment answers the question in the OP. In particular the fact that the kernel of $\partial_t+\lvert\partial_x\rvert_\gamma$ is positive. In a problem I work on, I am wondering whether I could prove the positivity of the kernel corresponding to the operator $\partial_t-P(\partial_x) $, with $P$ satisfying $P(i\xi)\ge c|\xi|^\alpha$, for some $\alpha, c>0$. Any suggestions or references?